# How to get a column value in DeleteCommand of RadGrid event

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

How can I get the value of a specific column in a RadGrid on DeleteCommand event? I tried these ways, but they all return empty values:

```
GridDataItem da = e.Item as GridDataItem;
string name = da["materialName"].Text;
```

or

```
name = RadGrid1.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex]["materialName"].Text;
```

or

```
name =  RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex]["materialName"].Text;
```

or

```
name =  RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items[e.Item.RowIndex]["materialName"].Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Label colTxt = (Label)e.Item.Cells[3].Text;

Label1.Text = colTxt.Text;
```

Try this. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

say the column is 'ID'

```
GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item; 
ID = Convert.ToInt32(item.GetDataKeyValue("ID"));
```